# Fetch immediate next and previous documents based on conditions in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

### Background

I have the following collection:

```json
article {
  title: String,
  slug: String,
  published_at: Date,
  ...
}
```

**MongoDB version: `4.4.10`**

### The problem

**Given an article, I want to fetch the immediate next and previous articles depending on the `published_at` field of that article.**

Let's say I have an article with `published_at` as `100`. And there are a lot of articles with `published_at` less than `100` and a lot having `published_at` more than `100`. I want the pipeline/query to fetch only the articles with `published_at` values of `99` or `101` or the nearest possible.

### Attempts

Here's my aggregation pipeline:

```js
const article = await db.article.findOne({ ... });

const nextAndPrev = db.article.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {
                    published_at: { $lt: article.published_at },
                    published_at: { $gt: article.published_at },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        $project: { slug: 1, title: 1 },
    },
    {
        $limit: 2,
    },
]);
```

It gives the wrong result (two articles after the provided article), which is expected as I know it's incorrect.

### Possible solutions

- I can do this easily using two separate `findOne` queries like the following:

  ```js
  const next = await db.article.findOne({ published_at: { $gt: article.published_at } });
  const prev = await db.article.findOne({ published_at: { $lt: article.published_at } });
  ```

  But I was curious to know of any available methods to do it in a single trip to the database.
- If I sort all the articles, offset it to the timestamp, and pull out the previous and next entries, that might work. I don't know the syntax.

Comment: Hey @ray, I've updated the question with a scenario/example. Does that help?

Comment: `db.version()` gives 4.4.10

Comment: I think your solutions returns documents whose `published_at` is **between a range**. my problem is given a date, return two documents having `published_at` immediately next and previous to that. Here, next and previous mean chronologically next and previous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238723/discussion-between-ray-and-abhijit).

Answer (score 6):

### Starting from MongoDB v5.0,

you can use `$setWindowFields` to fetch immediate prev/next documents according to certain sorting/ranking.

You can get the `_id` of current and next document through manipulating the `documents: [<prev offset>, <next offset>]` field. Similarly, for OP's scenario, it would be [-1, 1] to get the prev, current and next documents at once. Perform `$lookup` to fetch back the documents through the `_id` stored in the `nearIds` array.

```
{
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": null,
      "sortBy": {
        "published_at": 1
      },
      "output": {
        nearIds: {
          $addToSet: "$_id",
          window: {
            documents: [
              -1,
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P4XuQ3QKnlT) for your reference.